# Have central System for all computers in house

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I don't know if this can be done in an home environment but I would like to make a powerful system and have that providing a way for all my home computers to connect to having their own profile as if they were logging into their own account on a windows machine.

I would prefer a Windows 7 Based OS.

Is there such thing?

I would think Windows Server 2008 R2 with Hyper V machines associated to each account for logging in? Is that the only concept?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like the basic Roaming Profiles facility that all Windows Server editions (certainly since Server 2000) provides.

1. Install a windows server, and set it up as an Active Directory Server.
2. Join the workstations into the Domain you created as part of Step 1.

You now have centralised user management and profile storage at your fingertips.

Answer (score 1):

Both [Windows Home Server](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/windowshomeserver/default.mspx) (new release out soon which is 2008 R2 based) and [Windows Small Business Server 2011](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/products/servers/Pages/sbs_overview.aspx) offer features which should help.

Home server has the ability to sync accounts from various computers in a Work Group setting for many centralized tasks where as SBS is a single enterprise in a box setup with Active Directory, Exchange, SharePoint and WSUS.

Comment: I've tried out Vail 2011, and wasn't impressed by it, Server 2008 R2 is much more stable imo.

Comment: @sandeep - Vail is a beta (not even an RC release) and Server 2008 R2 is a stable retail product.